# Does 7zip work with archive manager?

Tags: 12.04, 7zip

Yesterday I installed 7zip on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I was able to extract a .rar file by using the Archive Manager.

Right click -> Extract Here

Today I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Then I installed 7zip from the Ubuntu Software Center and I tried to extract a .rar file the same way as last time and I see the following:

*"Could not open this file type.
There is no command installed for RAR archive files.
Do you want to search for a command to open this file?"*

I know that you can install unrar if you want to extract .rar files using the Archive Manager but I want to know why 7zip worked the last time and now after a fresh install it doesn't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure the [`p7zip-full`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/p7zip-full) and `p7zip-rar` packages are both installed. It is particularly `p7zip-rar` that is needed to provide RAR extraction functionality.

You can install those packages in the Software Center, or you may prefer to install them in a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I installed p7zip-rar and now it works fine.

Comment: The same applies to Ubuntu 18.04.